# Cobertura coverage report and check

Tags: java, maven, cobertura

I am currently working on an app and I want to generate the XML coverage report and also check while building if the coverage limits are achieved.

I am having a problem in making them work together.

```
<project>
...
<build>
  ...
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <configuration>
      <check>
        <branchRate>100</branchRate>
        <lineRate>100</lineRate>
        <haltOnFailure>true</haltOnFailure>
        <totalBranchRate>100</totalBranchRate>
        <totalLineRate>100</totalLineRate>
        <packageLineRate>100</packageLineRate>
        <packageBranchRate>100</packageBranchRate>
      </check>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>clean</goal>
          <goal>check</goal>
          <goal>cobertura</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

As it is, I get the following error: "Unable to prepare instrumentation directory. source and destination are the same directory".

But if I use only one goal it works. With "cobertura" I get my XML report and with "check" the app fails if it doesn't meet the limits.

How can I use them together?
I am using Java 8 and Maven 3.

Answer (score 0):

Add multiple executions, each with a single goal. And to ensure they run in order, assign each to a maven phase. Something like (you might want to change your phases used though):

```
<project>
...
<build>
  ...
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <configuration>
      <check>
        <branchRate>100</branchRate>
        <lineRate>100</lineRate>
        <haltOnFailure>true</haltOnFailure>
        <totalBranchRate>100</totalBranchRate>
        <totalLineRate>100</totalLineRate>
        <packageLineRate>100</packageLineRate>
        <packageBranchRate>100</packageBranchRate>
      </check>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>clean-corbertura</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>clean</goal>
        </goals>
          <phase>initialize</phase>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>check-corbertura</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>run-corbertura</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>cobertura</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

More info at https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html